# Russian MO 2004 Question involving the AM-GM inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I'm reading Secrets in Inequalities by Pham Kim Hung, and I'm having trouble understanding this proof from a problem from the 2004 Russian MO.

Let a,b,c be positive real numbers and 
$a + b +c = 3$. Prove that
$\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c} \ge ab + bc + ca$.

The proof is as follows.

First he notes that
$2(ab + bc + ca) = (a + b +c)^2 - a^2 -b^2 -c^2$ which implies that
$\sum_{cyc} a + 2 \sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a} \ge 9$, which must be true because of the AM-GM inequality because
$\sum_{cyc} a + 2 \sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a} = \sum_{cyc}(a + \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{a}) \ge 3 \sum_{cyc} a = 9$

I don't quite understand how the last line follows from the AM-GM inequality.

Thanks

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336362/prove-sqrta-sqrtb-sqrtc-ge-ab-bc-ca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a typo as I read that book and own one and some typos were spotted by me as well. It should be: $a^2+\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{a} \geq 3\sqrt[3]{a^2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a}} = 3a$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Ya he had a type on the first line of the proof as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Fine, and it is a nice problem.