# Russian MO 2004 $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c} \geq ab + bc + ca$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, functional-inequalities

I have a doubt on a proof included in "Secrets in Inequalities" by Pham Kim Hung. The exercise is to prove $$\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c} \geq ab + bc + ca$$ for a, b, c whose sum is 3.

His approach is the following

He observes that:
$$2(ab + bc + ca) = (a + b + c)^2 - (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)$$

And he says that the equation above is equivalent to the inequality below(which is what gives me doubt):

$$\sum_{cyc} a^2 + 2\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a} \geq 9$$

How does he get to $2\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a} $? Does he get this out of the blue? Or is there some logic behind this?

Comment: [Strongly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409947/russian-mo-2004-question-involving-the-am-gm-inequality?rq=1)

Comment: @GabrielRomon Yes, and there the OP was advised to post a new question.

Comment: What is a cyc below the sum?

Comment: Just multiply the original inequality by $2$ and substitute the $2(ab+bc+ca)$ from observed equality.

Comment: The cyc below the sum means that the sum will be of the permutations of the letter in that equation. For example: $\sum_{cyc} 2ab/c = 2ab/c + 2bc/a + 2ca/b$

Comment: I see what you are asking now... Didn't get it on first read. You have just confused word inequality and equality. What is really meant is that $\sum_{cyc} a^2 + 2\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a} \geq 9$ is equivalent to the original inequality $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c} \geq ab + bc + ca$, that's all.

Comment: -Sil I got it now, your first comment was the one that helped me very much. My problem was when substituting the equality in the inequality and rearranging. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 2):

> And he says that the equation above is equivalent to the inequality below (which is what gives me doubt):
>   $$\sum_{cyc} a^2 + 2\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a} \geq 9 \tag{1}$$
>
> How does he get to $2\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a}$?

The *original* inequality (*not* the equation) is equivalent to $(1)$ because, after multiplying by $\,2\,$, it is:

$$
2\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a} \ge 2 \sum_{cyc} ab = \sum_{cyc} a(b+c) = \sum_{cyc}a(3-a) = 3 \sum_{cyc}a - \sum_{cyc} a^2 = 9 - \sum_{cyc} a^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2+2\sqrt{a})\geq3\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{a^2\cdot(\sqrt{a})^2}=$$
$$=3\sum_{cyc}a=9=(a+b+c)^2=\sum_{cyc}(a^2+2ab),$$
which gives $$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\geq ab+ac+bc.$$

Comment: The OP actually did not ask for proving the inequality at all :)

Comment: I know. See please better my solution. In my answer there is the needed thing exactly.

Comment: It explains why it makes sense, however it did not tell me how Pham got to $\sqrt{etc}$. But still, I thank you very much, because your answer explained the last step of the proof.

Comment: You are welcome!